# Is there a tutorial for using cakephp and uploadify?

Tags: cakephp, jquery-plugins, uploadify

Does anyone have a good tutorial implementing cakephp and uploadify?

Answer (score 4):

Have you seen this one: http://phpdev.ro/how-to-use-uploadify-with-cakephp.html

Comment: Thanks alot a was smashing my head with an italian version

Answer (score 1):

I've also created a CakePHP plugin for Uploadify. I guess it's still kinda beta, but it seems to work for my needs. It's also open-source, so it can be a good starting point for you if it doesn't 100% suit your needs.

http://www.am05.com/2011/01/06/using-uploadify-in-cakephp

Comment: good one. It solves the authentication problem for uploadify.

Answer (score 0):

The url for that tutorial has changed.

The correct url is http://phpdev.ro/how-to-use-uploadify-with-cakephp.html